# using clojurescript with jquery?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Here is what i am trying to do, I can replace Dom with jQuery, but I don't know how to get the Dom value. That's shame.
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/thorstadt/1096382)
This is a gist which I followed it.
So I ask the origin author, but no response yet.
PS: I just want to try some cljs in browser, so I didn't use any lib like jayq.
I have tried something like `(.val "yes")`, but it seems to be wrong.

```
(ns hello-world.jquerytest)
(enable-console-print!)
(def jquery (js* "$"))

(defn x []
  (-> 
    (jquery ".meat")
      (.html "yes")))

(jquery
  (fn []
    (x)
    (-> (jquery "li.numbers")
      (.html "pink")
      (.append "banana"))))
```

Comment: `.html` returns a string. You probably want to use clojure's `doto`. If this solves the problem please answer it yourself with some nice explanation and references.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but it won't be necessary to add `doto`, just list down the function like a pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer based on Vanessa's comment
I tried

```
(defn x []
  (->  
    (jquery ".meat")
    (.html)
    (println)))
```

It will print the value which I want.
If I am using `doto`
It will print #<[object Object]> in console which I do not want.

```
(defn x []
  (->  
    (doto
      (jquery ".meat")
      (.html)
      (println))))
```

Comment: You changed your code. If you want to use the `.append` call at the end then you need to use `doto`. There is no point in wrapping a form in `->` with one single form. It doesn't do any thing.

Comment: `(defn y []
  (doto 
    (jquery ".meat")
    (.html)
    (println)))   ` I tied this either, do you mean I can remove the `->`. But this one still print  #<[object Object]>, and I found `->` seems does the same action like `doto`

Comment: You're confused by using `->` and doto. Just write them out without `->`.